# On emacs, I can't jump to tags in GTAGS SELECT buffer

Tags: emacs, gnu-global

On emacs, I can't jump to tags in GTAGS SELECT buffer. I get `"Buffer is read-only: <buffer *GTAGS SELECT*>"` error when I press return.

- Mac OS X 10.8.1
- Emacs 24.2
- gtags GNU GLOBAL 6.2.4 (installed by homebrew)
- gtags.el 3.3 (installed by package.el)

`"C-h k <return>"` in GTAGS SELECT buffer showed the following message:

```
RET (translated from <return>) runs the command newline, which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.

It is bound to RET.

(newline &optional ARG)

Insert a newline, and move to left margin of the new line if it's blank.
If `use-hard-newlines' is non-nil, the newline is marked with the
text-property `hard'.
With ARG, insert that many newlines.
Call `auto-fill-function' if the current column number is greater
than the value of `fill-column' and ARG is nil.
```

Comment: Can you do a `C-h k <return>` in your gtags select buffer? This will show us what command will be triggered by the return key. Maybe it is overriden with something. I am using the xgtags.el mode for gtags, but it's a rather old mode. I did not yet try gtags.el.

Comment: I updated the description to include the result of c-h k <return>.

Comment: And that's your problem right there, I think. In my xgtags mode I get `RET (translated from <return>) runs the command xgtags-select-tag-near-point, which is an interactive Lisp
function in `xgtags.el'.` -- I guess that the gtags select buffer should have something similar, but for some reason, return is bound to newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use GNU global, however a quick google search hints that downgrading the gtags.el to an older version might help:
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-global/2011-12/msg00003.html

---

EDIT: (cannot add comment to first post so editing here)

as Arne said, the RET key is not bound correctly for some reason. For gtags-select-mode RET should be bound to (gtags-select-tag) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your information. But I've updated gtags.el from 3.3 to 3.6, and found out it works well. I don't know why. gtags 3.3 installed by package.el might be not compatible with global-6.2.4.

gtags.el 3.6 is included in global-6.2.4.tar.gz. You can download global-6.2.4.tar.gz from here: http://www.gnu.org/software/global/download.html.